# Dropdown bootstrap with input - Bind click function on<li>, unable to check input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap dropdown with inputs inside and I want to check the inputs (radio or checkbox) when I click `li` elements, so I bind the click function below on every `li` elements in my code. When I click on `li` elements the relative inputs are checked but not when I click on inputs directly. What's wrong?

```js
function li_click(this_li) {
  console.log(this_li.find('input').attr('type'));
  if (this_li.find('input').attr('type') == 'radio') {
    this_li.parent().find('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    this_li.parent().parent().find('button').text(this_li.find('input').val() + ' ').append($('<span>').addClass('caret'));
    this_li.find('input').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this_li.find('input').is(':checked'));
    if (this_li.find('input').is(':checked'))
      this_li.find('input').prop('checked', false);
    else
      this_li.find('input').prop('checked', true);

  }
  (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault(): event.returnValue = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropdown_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="Select" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Select&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="dropdown_dd" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_btn">
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="li_click($(this))">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_0" type="radio" value="MASTER"><span>MASTER</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="li_click($(this))">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_1" type="radio" value="SLAVE"><span>SLAVE</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please do not shout at us. THANK YOU

Comment: COULD YOU PLEASE TURN THE VOLUME DOWN?

Comment: I CAN'T HEAR YOU OVER THE SOUND OF HOW AWESOME I AM.

Answer (score 0):

`(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;` is the problem in your code. If you really want to include that line, you can resolve it by adding a 0ms delay before checking your input:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this_li.find('input').prop('checked', true);
}, 0);
```

However, I think you'll be better off rewriting your jQuery. Rather than using `onClick`, you should be binding to the elements.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/82gfcaaL/) with the `setTimeout(f,0)` working. 
[Here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/82gfcaaL/3/) where the jQuery has been rewritten to a more 'standard' imp

Comment: IMO there is nothing to understand - its simple coding in a rush ;-)

Comment: thanks, i delete the preventDefault but it's noisy the return on top when click on <li>. i think it's 'cause of <a> tag inside <li>

Answer (score 0):

And here is a **clean** version without even using javascript for it

`label` - tag does the trick

**UPDATED**

JS to set DropDown text

```js
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        $('#dropdown_btn').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<style>
label { font-weight: normal !important; }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dropdown_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="Select" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Select&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="dropdown_dd" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_btn">
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_0" type="checkbox" value="MASTER"><label for="g_0">MASTER</label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_1" type="checkbox" value="SLAVE"><label for="g_1">SLAVE</label>
      </a>
    </li>
<li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_2" name="uniqueName" type="radio" value="MASTER"><label for="g_2">MASTER 2</label>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <input class="myinput" id="g_3" name="uniqueName" type="radio" value="SLAVE"><label for="g_3">SLAVE 2</label>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i need js because i want the checked value displayed on dropdown button.

Comment: Moreover i'm unable to write a correct click function for the checkboxes, because in this case too i need that the click on <li> tag (that contains <input>) check the correspondent <input>. How can i do?

Comment: I have updated the answer - but you better take a closer look into jquery (or JS) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

If you give the radio inputs the same name then you can avoid using inline onclick=""s

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
<button id="dropdown_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="Select" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Select&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id="dropdown_dd" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_btn">
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"><input class="myinput" id="g_0" type="radio" value="MASTER" name="same"><span>MASTER</span></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"><input class="myinput" id="g_1" type="radio" value="SLAVE" name="same"><span>SLAVE</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
$("#dropdown_dd li span").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).prev().click();
});
</script>
```